# Gráfico de um ataque de negação de serviço em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, matplotlib

Amigos,

Gerei o seguinte gráfico:

[image: Número de conexões por segundo]

O código utilizado foi o seguinte:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as dates
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

x = []
y = []

dataset = open("./datasetDdos10Abril2017_unixtime_slowloris.csv","r")
##separacao no csv eh por virgulas

for line in dataset:
    line = line.strip() #23,24\n -> 23,24 retira a quebra de linha
    X,Y = line.split(",") #separador eh a virgula
    x.append( float(X))
    y.append(float (Y))

dataset.close()

x1 = [datetime.fromtimestamp(int(d)) for d in x]

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'))

y1 = []
v = 0
for i in sorted(y):
    if(abs(i-v > 50)):
        y1.append(i)
        v = i

plt.plot(x1, y, 'ro')

plt.title("Número de Conexões por segundo: Ataque Sockstress")
plt.ylabel("Número de Conexões por segundo")
plt.xlabel('Tempo')
plt.xticks(x1)
plt.yticks(y1)

#plt.gca().set_ylim([0, 29800])
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

Ao mostrar o gráfico a um professor, este disse que o gráfico não estava muito claro e sugeriu fazê-lo como um gráfico em barras.

Alguma sugestão de como apresentar melhor os dados?

Como fazer um gráfico em barras usando Python, como os dados abaixo?

O arquivo com os dados (CSV) está disponível em: https://ufile.io/cnhl5

Comment: O gráfico em barras ficaria bem melhor, só vi o valor das 09:45 depois de olhar bem a tela, já com o de barras estaria muito mais claro pois a barra ocupa um espaço bem maior no gráfico.

Comment: @Tiago Oliveira de Freitas : obrigado! Ajudou muito a entender o motivo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes fazer o seguinte:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as dates
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

x = []
y = []
with open("./datasetDdos10Abril2017_unixtime_slowloris.csv") as f:
    for l in f:
        X,Y = l.split(",") #separador eh a virgula
        x.append(float(X))
        y.append(float (Y))

x1 = [datetime.fromtimestamp(int(d)) for d in x]
y_pos = [idx for idx, i in enumerate(y)]

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'))

y1 = []
v = 0
y_sorted = sorted(y)
for i in y_sorted:
    if(abs(i-v > 50)):
        y1.append(i)
        v = i

plt.bar(y_pos, y, align='edge', color="blue", alpha=0.5, width=0.5) # <--- EDICAO PRINCIPAL

plt.title("Número de Conexões por segundo: Ataque Sockstress")
plt.ylabel("Número de Conexões por segundo")
plt.xlabel('Tempo')
plt.xticks(y_pos, x1, size='small',rotation=35, ha="right")
plt.yticks(y1)
plt.ylim(ymin=y_sorted[0]-200) # valor minimo do eixo y

plt.show()
```

Comment: você acha o gráfico em barras melhor neste caso? não entendi o porquê de não estar claro o gráfico!

Comment: Sinceramente concordo com o teu professor @EdS, com a bolinhas não se consegue ter tanta precisão visual acerca do valor y de cada uma

Comment: gráfico em barras ficaria melhor?

Comment: Foi o que pediste @EdS, assim ficas com dois e perguntas isso ao teu prof, e sinceramente acho que sim, fica

Comment: tentei rodar o código mas está apresentando o seguinte erro:

https://ufile.io/mgln3

Poderia, por favor, ajuda?

Comment: Experimenta colocar `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` na primeira do código, antes de tudo @EdS. Isso é por causa dos caracteres especiais, "ç, palavras com acento, etc..." acho que estás a usar python 2.x, certo?

Comment: uso tanto o 2.7 quanto o 3.6 mas eu rodei no Python 2.7

Comment: agora rodou! Deus te abençoe!

Comment: criei outra pergunta. Caso tenha tempo:  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/231150/gr%c3%a1fico-em-barras-feito-em-python-ficou-estranho-alguma-sugest%c3%a3o-de-como-melh