# Gráfico em barras feito em Python ficou "estranho". Alguma sugestão de como melhorá-lo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, matplotlib

Amigos,

O seguinte gráfico foi gerado:

[image: Grafico sem ataques]

O código utilizado foi o seguinte:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as dates
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

x = []
y = []
with open("dataset_semAtaques__10Abril2017_1min.csv") as f:
    for l in f:
        X,Y = l.split(",") #separador eh a virgula
        x.append(float(X))
        y.append(float (Y))

x1 = [datetime.fromtimestamp(int(d)) for d in x]
y_pos = [idx for idx, i in enumerate(y)]

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'))

y1 = []
v = 0
y_sorted = sorted(y)
for i in y_sorted:
    if(abs(i-v > 50)):
        y1.append(i)
        v = i

plt.bar(y_pos, y, align='edge', color="blue", alpha=0.5, width=0.5) # <--- EDICAO PRINCIPAL

plt.title("Número de Conexões por segundo: Sem Ataques")
plt.ylabel("Número de Conexões por segundo")
plt.xlabel('Tempo')
plt.xticks(y_pos, x1, size='small',rotation=35, ha="right")
plt.yticks(y1)
plt.ylim(ymin=y_sorted[0]-200) # valor minimo do eixo y

plt.show()
```

O gráfico em barras ficou muito estranho.

Alguma sugestão de como apresentar melhor o gráfico com os dados abaixo?

O arquivo com os dados (CSV) está disponível em: https://ufile.io/h8la7

Comment: Esse código com python3.5 no meu o gráfico é assim: https://ibb.co/mUwbnQ

Comment: @Miguel: você está usando o dataset da outra questão. O dataset acima são poucas conexões, tipo: 0, 8,2 ...

Comment: @Miguel: O dataset novo é  https://ufile.io/h8la7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é o intervalo que tinhas para o eixo do `y`, `n-200` como valor minímo, e ia dar negativo visto que o espetro dos teus valores é no intervalo `0 <= y < 10`.

Assim resulta bem, testado com python3.5:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as dates
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

x = []
y = []
with open("dataset_semataques__10abril2017_1min.csv") as f:
    for l in f:
        X,Y = l.split(",") #separador eh a virgula
        x.append(float(X))
        y.append(float (Y))

x1 = [datetime.fromtimestamp(int(d)) for d in x]
y_pos = [idx for idx, i in enumerate(y)]

plt.figure(figsize=(17,9))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'))

plt.bar(y_pos, y, align='edge', color="blue", alpha=0.5, width=0.5) # <--- EDICAO PRINCIPAL
plt.title("Número de Conexões por segundo: Sem Ataques")
plt.ylabel("Número de Conexões por segundo")
plt.xlabel('Tempo')
plt.xticks(y_pos, x1, size='small',rotation=35, ha="right")
plt.yticks(y)
plt.ylim(ymax=max(y)+1) # valor maximo do eixo y
#plt.ylim(ymin=min(y)-1) # valor minimo do eixo y

plt.show()
```

Comment: como exibir os valores do eixo y? Não aparecem:

https://ufile.io/p7b9g

Comment: Aparecem sim @EdS, copia o código que está em cima depois da ultima edição

Comment: gratidao. desculpe pelas perguntas bobas!

Comment: Sem problema, todos as temos @EdS